# Flutter flame sprite duplication on Android but not Iphone?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flame

Making a game using Flutter Flame engine and AndroidStudio for development. The render function uses canvas.save() and canvas.render() functions that ensure that the screen is clear between frames (to prevent duplicate sprite drawing). On IPhone simulator the app runs as expected, however on multiple Android Simulators duplicate sprites are rendered. Can't figure out why this is happening... Any help appreciated!

[image]

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flame/components/component.dart';
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


class ThisGame extends Game {
  final SharedPreferences storage;
  Size screenSize;
  double tileSize;

  Player player;
  double spriteSize = 128;
  double timeElapsed = 0;

  ThisGame(this.storage) {
    initialize();
  }

  initialize() async {
    resize(await Flame.util.initialDimensions());
    player = Player();
    player.x = 0;
    player.y = 0;
  }

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    player.render(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  void update(double t) {
    timeElapsed += t;
    if (timeElapsed > 1) {
      timeElapsed = 0;
      player.y += t * 300;
      player.x += t * 300;
    }
  }

  @override
  void resize(Size size) {
    screenSize = size;
    tileSize = screenSize.width / 9;
  }
}

class Player extends SpriteComponent {
  Player() : super.square(128.0, 'player.png') {
    this.angle = 0.0;
   }

}
```

Comment: Interesting, You might want to try in BlueStack or Nov, or other famous simulator to see If It's working. I don't know this issue either, but just curious about the result in those famous simulators.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to handle the render method yourself, just add your SpriteComponent to the game and it will handle the rendering for you.

```
class ThisGame extends Game {
  final SharedPreferences storage;
  Size screenSize;
  double tileSize;

  Player player;
  double spriteSize = 128;
  double timeElapsed = 0;

  ThisGame(this.storage) {
    initialize();
  }

  initialize() async {
    resize(await Flame.util.initialDimensions());
    player = Player();
    player.x = 0;
    player.y = 0;
    add(player); // <-- Like this
  }

  @override
  void update(double t) {
    super.update(t) // Also don't forget to call super
    timeElapsed += t;
    if (timeElapsed > 1) {
      timeElapsed = 0;
      player.y += t * 300;
      player.x += t * 300;
    }
  }

  @override
  void resize(Size size) {
    screenSize = size;
    tileSize = screenSize.width / 9;
  }
}

class Player extends SpriteComponent {
  Player() : super.square(128.0, 'player.png') {
    this.angle = 0.0;
  }
}
```

Also, don't forget to call `super.update(t)` in your update override.